# If $U: L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is unitary, is $U: L^2(G)\rightarrow L^2(G)$ unitary?

Tags: functional-analysis

Assume $U: L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)\rightarrow L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ is unitary, is then $U$ restricted on $L^2(G)$ also unitary when $G\subseteq \mathbb{R}^d$?

i.e. is $U\vert_{L^2(G)}$ unitary using the identification $f\in L^2(G)$ if and only if there is a function in $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $g=\chi_G f$.

Note that $U\vert_{L^2(G)}$ is continuous since $L^2(G)\subseteq L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$.

I would suppose $U\vert_{L^2(G)}$ is unitary, since for any $f\in L^2(G)$ one finds a element $g\in L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ such that $g\vert_G=f$. Therefore $U\vert_{L^2(G)}$ stays onto. And for any $f,g \in L^2(G)$ one finds

$\langle f,g\rangle_{L^2(G)}=\langle \chi_G f,\chi_Gg\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}=\langle U\chi_G f,U\chi_Gg\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}=
\langle \chi_G f,U^*U\chi_Gg\rangle_{L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)}
=\langle f,U^*U\chi_Gg\rangle_{L^2(G)}=
\langle U^*Uf,g\rangle_{L^2(G)}=\langle Uf,Ug\rangle_{L^2(G)}$

i.e. it is surjective, continuous and preserves the dotproduct.

Anyone has a better idea or different opinion?

Comment: Well, no.  But what do you mean by restrict?  If you mean $\pi U\pi$ where pi is the projection $L^2(\Bbb{R}^d)\to L^2(G)$ (multiplication by the characteristic function of $G$) then no.  For example, take $U$ a translation in some direction by a distance of one.  And take $G$ a fundamental domain for the translation - then $\pi U\pi$ is zero.

Comment: @ChadK are you sure? I edited the post, and explained why I think its true.

Comment: Please define what you mean by restrict $U$ to $L^2(G)$.  You need a map $\mathscr{B}(L^2(\Bbb{R}^d))\to\mathscr{B}(L^2(G))$ where $\mathscr{B}$ means bounded linear operators.

Comment: @ChadK thank you for pointing that out, I defined what I meant by "restricted"

Comment: $U\vert_{L^2(G)}$ is an operator from $L^2(G)$ to $L^2(\Bbb{R}^d)$.  It's not a map from a Hilbert space to itself.  This is called an *isometry*, not 'unitary'.  Unitary is either an isometry from a Hilbert space *onto* itself, or sometimes an isometry from a Hilbert space *onto* another one.  Restricting $U$ like this stays isometric, but it not usually going to be onto $L^2(\Bbb{R}^d)$.

Comment: It is straightforward. If $V$ is a subspace of an inner product space $H$ and $T:H\to H$ is unitary then $T:V\to T(V)$ is unitary as well.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: You notice that the title says $U: L^2(G)\to L^2(G)$, yes?

Comment: @ChadK I have missed the title. Then we must require that $L^2(G)$ is invariant for $U.$ Otherwise the question does not make sense.

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc thanks for pointing that out. What if $U$ would be the unitary operator on $L^2$ from Plancherels theorem and $G$ be bounded then we would have $Uf= \hat{f}$ for all $f\in L^2(G)$. Than $U(L^2(G))=L^2(G)$, no?

Comment: I am not sure if there is a subspace $L^2(G)$ of $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ invariant for the Fourier transform.

Comment: okay, thanks for all youre help anyways

Comment: @RyszardSzwarc: Except in the trivial cases, this never holds. To see this, use that modulations keep $L^2(G)$ invariant, but correspond to translations of the Fourier transform.

Comment: @PhoemueX Thanks. I have overlooked an easy argument.